# Render a HashMap from JSP and display in a Table

Tags: java, jsp, twitter-bootstrap, servlets, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a class that generates simple statistics for user. I have called that class and exposed the HashMap that I want in my servlet class.

```
    StatProvider stat = new StatProvider(uId);
    request.setAttribute("uStat", stat.getStats());
```

How in my JSP I am trying to render it inside bootstrap panel, and where key, value of map is in table like structure. I started as follows:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Stats</h3></div>
                <c:forEach items="$uStat" var="entry">
                    <label>${entry.key}, ${entry.value}</label>
                </c:forEach>                
        </div>      
    </div>
 </div>
```

Until I figure out the table, I thought I ll just put inside a label to see if I am rendering the map correctly, but I am getting following error:

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'key' not found on type java.lang.String
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:266)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:243)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:353)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:97)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:967)
```

I am new to both servlet technology and bootstrap. During my search I also found out about google code project JSPF not sure if that needed to resolve this issue. It would be great if someone can provide good set of instructions on solving the problem. In my JSP I have imported the `c.tld` and `fn.tld`.

Comment: Could it be a typo missing curly braces around "$uStat"? <c:forEach items="${uStat}" var="entry">

Comment: spot on... Shoot. Thanks.

Comment: @Susie you are free to post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was missing curly brackets @Susie pointed out the problem and allow me to put the answer:

```
<c:forEach items="${uStat}" var="entry">
```